# loop for column names for codebook printing null

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

This seems like it should be so simple....

I am trying to make a loop that assigns column names to things. But, when I try to column name the looped name, then I just get null. For example:

```
mtcars1 <- mtcars
mtcars2 <- mtcars
colnames(mtcars2) <- paste0(colnames(mtcars), "2")


codebook <- for(x in 1:2){
  colnames(paste0("mtcars",x))
} %>% reduce(full_join)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `full_join`, there was no `by`.  Usually, `by` picks up column names that are common in both.  As the second dataset columns are all modified by appending `2` at the end, it won't do.  Here, we specified `by` with a column name so that it works.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mget(paste0("mtcars", 1:2)) %>% 
    reduce(full_join, by = c("gear" = "gear2"))
```

---

Also, `paste` step only returns the object names in string, we need `get` (if single dataset) or `mget` (if more than one - returns a list of values)

```
for(x in 1:2) print(colnames(get(paste0("mtcars", x))))
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
 [1] "mpg2"  "cyl2"  "disp2" "hp2"   "drat2" "wt2"   "qsec2" "vs2"   "am2"   "gear2" "carb2"
```

Comment: Okay, but is there a way to do the colnames in the loop? Because I'd like to do other things in the loop for the full data.

Comment: @tchoup In the `for` loop, I showed how to retrieve the `colnames` .  Isn't that you wanted